# Python AWS Apprunner Service Failing Health Check

Tags: python, tcpserver, amazon-app-runner

New to Apprunner and trying to get a vanilla Python application to deploy successfully but continuing to fail the TCP Health Checks. The following is some relevant portions of the service and Apprunner console logs:

Service Logs:

```
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] Step 5/5 : EXPOSE 80
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] ---> Running in abcxyz 
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] Removing intermediate container abcxyz 
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] ---> f3701b7ee4cf
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] Successfully built abcxyz 
2023-02-18T15:20:20.856-05:00   [Build] Successfully tagged application-image:latest
2023-02-18T15:30:49.152-05:00   [AppRunner] Failed to deploy your application source code.
```

Console:

```
02-18-2023 03:30:49 PM [AppRunner] Deployment with ID : 123456789 failed. Failure reason : Health check failed.
02-18-2023 03:30:38 PM [AppRunner] Health check failed on port '80'. Check your configured port number. For more information, read the application logs.
02-18-2023 03:24:21 PM [AppRunner] Performing health check on port '80'.
02-18-2023 03:24:11 PM [AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image for privately accessible service.
02-18-2023 03:23:59 PM [AppRunner] Successfully built source code.
```

My app is a vanilla, non-networked Python application into which I've added a `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` running on a `TCPServer` configured to run as a seperate thread as follows:

```
import socketserver
import threading
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


# handler for server
class HealthCheckHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self) -> None:
        self.send_response(code=200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("""<html><body>hello, client.</body><html>""".encode('utf-8'))


# runs the server
def run_healthcheck_server():
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("127.0.0.1", 80), HealthCheckHandler) as httpd:
        print(f"Fielding health check requests on: 80")
        httpd.serve_forever()


# dummy
def my_app_logic():
    while True:
        print('hello, server.')
        time.sleep(5)


# wrapper to run primary application logic AND TCPServer
def main():

    # run the server in a thread
    threading.Thread(target=run_healthcheck_server).start()

    # run my app
    my_app_logic()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works fine on my local machine and I see "hello, client." in my browser when going to `127.0.0.1` and a stream of `hello, server.` messages every 5 seconds in my console.

I don't know much about networking and the only reason I'm incorporating this into the app is to facilitate the AWS HealthCheck which I can't disable in the AppRunner service. I am trying to understand if the issue is how I'm *trying* to handle TCP requests from AWS' Health Checker or if it's something else on the Apprunner side.

Comment: What have you configured as the health check on App Runner?

Comment: http status check for `/`

Comment: nope - ended up deploying with a different provider out of frustration